# Add Dynamic table in custom node - Node-Red

Tags: javascript, node-red

Am new to  node-red and am learning basic flows. Currently am trying to create a custom node that displays a table in configuration dialogue. I am able to do this with static data.

[image: link]

However I want the table to be dynamic and append rows based on msg.payload from another node. Can you please point me in the right way.

Comment: Shows a table where? As a response to a HTTP-in request, using the Node-RED Dashboard or in a Node's configuration dialogue? We need a lot more detail here.

Comment: Sorry hardillb, I wasn't clear in question. Table to be displayed in Node's configuration dialogue - as shown in the link - [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ufOk.jpg). I was able to do with static table, but wasn't sure on how to do with dynamic data

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67618319/edit) the question to add detail. But the config dialogue should NOT change based on data flowing through the node

Comment: Thanks hardillb, I have edited the question. I understand the optimal way is to use the dashboard and not the configuration dialogue, but , is there still a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To add dynamic content to the conf dialogue you need to make a AJAX REST request to a HTTP endpoint setup by the node. There are examples of this in the core nodes, e.g. the serial port node.

But as I said in the comments, the configuration node should be using information from messages flowing through the system. There are many reasons for this but here are just a few.

1. The editor is NOT a dashboard
2. What happens when you start with a blank canvas? You drag all the nodes on to the canvas but haven't deployed yet? There will never have been any messages in the system to use to populate the configuration dialogue for that node.
3. What happens on a restart? The node will be instantiated before any messages flow, and you have no way of knowing if the same data will later enter the flow.